# Pandas data frame format datetime issue python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I Have a data frame but it is not in the proper format --

**out** is a data frame -

| Name | 2/18/2022 | 3/31/2022 | 2022-13-01 | 11/15/2022 | 12/14/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 21 | 2 | 21 | 21 | 21 |

My expected output is that all heading dates should be in one format and in order (asc or desc)

Comment: Are your date values stored as simple strings in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Second and better approach:

You can also receive similar result using `sort_index()` with the `key` argument:
`df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='mixed'))`.

First approach:

You can transpose the DataFrame, use `pd.to_datetime()` with argument `format='mixed'` and then re-transpose it in its original format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict({'2/18/2022': 21, '3/31/2022': 2, '2022-11-01': 21,
                        '11/15/2022': 21, '12/14/2022': 21}
                       ),
                  index=['One']
                  )

df.loc['dates', :] = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='mixed')
transposed = df.T

sorted_df = transposed.sort_values('dates')
del sorted_df['dates']

    2/18/2022 3/31/2022 2022-11-01 11/15/2022 12/14/2022
One      21.0       2.0       21.0       21.0       21.0
```

Comment: When I run this code I receive the error message `ValueError: time data '2/18/2022' does not match format 'mixed' (match)`.